# Is it meaningful to take difference between two ratio?

Tags: logistic, ratio

Assume we are investigating a simplified satisfaction survey data, where the outcome is binary: satisfied and not satisfied. We have two years data with ~10K samples for each year.

**Is the ratio difference between two years meaningful?** Say, someone says, this year we have 60% satisfied, and last year it is 50% satisfied, we have 10% increase.

The reason I think it may be flawed, is because this ratio is bounded from $0$ to $1$ and it should have some non-linear relationship in there. Like a "sigmoid function".

[image]

In other words, I think increasing 10% from 90% to 100% vs increase 10% from 50% to 60% are really different, and the former is harder. We should not only talk about the percentile changes.

Am I right?

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in the difference between probability and quantile.  In 'R' the qnorm function returns how many standard deviations one is from the mean instead of the probability of occurrence.  qnorm(0.999) gives 3.09 standard deviations.  Perhaps you are looking for difference in the quantile function.  This gives about 1.44 standard deviations of difference between 0.95 and 0.999.

Comment: This seems more like a theoretical/conceptual problem than a statistical problem. That said, you might want to consider an arcsine transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original numbers (num_satisfaction_yearA, num_unsatisfaction_yearA, num_satisfaction_yearB, num_unsatisfaction_yearB) you can compare these proportions with a Fisher's exact test.

You are right, a 10% is not the same regardless the magnitude of the values